# Maping a type with P in K does not preserve modifiers

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
export type Message =
  { type: 'auth', user: string, password?: string } |
  { type: 'getData'}

export type Answer = 
  { type: 'auth', success: boolean } |
  { type: 'getData', someData: any}

export type MessageType = Message["type"]
export type ExcludeTypeField<A> = { [K in Exclude<keyof A, "type">>]: A[K] }
export type ExtractParameters<A, T> = ExcludeTypeField<Extract<A, { type: T }>>

type a = ExtractParameters<Message, 'auth'>
```

It allows me to extract type information for Message and Answer types by only providing the `type` field. However, for some reason, the optional modifier for `password` is removed. I guess it's because the type mapping doesn't care what was once optional and just creates a new type with all keys.

I worked around this issue by replacing `ExcludeTypeField` with:

```js
export type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T]
export type ExcludeTypeField<A> = { [K in Exclude<Exclude<keyof A, "type">, OptionalKeys<A>>]: A[K] } & { [K in Extract<Exclude<keyof A, "type">, OptionalKeys<A>>]?: A[K] }
```

This is super verbose because I basically just merge two type mappings (one time excluding all optional parameters and not time picking them while adding the optional modifier back).
I feel like there should be a simpler way. Is there?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), which takes a type `T` and removes all any properties with keys in `K` from the type definition, **preserving any modifiers in `T`**:

```
type ExtractParameters<A, T> = Omit<Extract<A, { type: T }>, "type">
```

You can verify that it works as desired:

```
type A = ExtractParameters<Message, 'auth'>
/* type A = {
    user: string;
    password?: string | undefined;
} */
```

By the way, `Omit<T, K>` isn't some built-in TypeScript magic; it's [part of the standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1516) and you could have defined it yourself.  Your `ExcludeTypeField` is close, but missing a crucial layer of indirection in order to make the mapping *homomorphic* (which, among other things, preserves modifiers).  You either need the mapped type to include `K in keyof XYZ` directly, *or*, `K in P` where `P` is a generic type parameter declared like `P extends keyof XYZ`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#12826](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12826) for the PR that implements this.

So you'd have to change this:

```
type ExcludeTypeField<A> = { [K in Exclude<keyof A, "type">>]: A[K] }
```

to something like this:

```
type _ExcludeTypeField<A, P extends keyof A> = { [K in P]: A[K] }
type ExcludeTypeField<A> = _ExcludeTypeField<A, Exclude<keyof A, "type">>
```

and then it would have worked for you the way you wanted:

```
type B = ExcludeTypeField<{ type: string; a?: number; readonly b: boolean }>
/* type B = {
    a?: number | undefined;
    readonly b: boolean;
} */
```

But of course it's much easier to just use `Omit<T, K>` which already handles this fiddly stuff for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeAUFKBvKokAXFAORICuwAFqQDRQXwQBOJ8wLAlgHYoNgkiAO4B7FgBMA-O068UUAL5QAPtjwFwEEqTTAAIkmBJSSzJkLQAgj3jDWULDnyWdlGvSjwKAYx8J4EgAjUVEAGwgkHiVVdRctHT1DY094UQBbCGSkEiiQMwstKABRAA9OJB9gAAUkFiRM4FZ4AB4rBgAVAD5HKAB5dK5gFrKKqraGeOIoDqUuhgAiSwWu80soK17R+qra+sbmlrhEVAgGcipaLoBuTAB6ACpNSA3e3HUcJlZZbj5bnBwghE4mkP3kqkYPAkEAAZrwIBJbsoHndzIUXgB9Mo+MIUaEdLQAMS4EDCEgmUGqUAg5QgUPgUAA1hAQKIYRseugNABtADSUF4lIAuiQrHyhWZ1tjcfiiSSyW1OVAsaUcXiIATIMTSeT2iVVTKIC1maz2XqlloVjc1kUAEJbA3qzUQbUKqbaLxyP5QJAyKA8CjpIKsa5QFiRCSiHhhfJBYKhCJROb3J7re1c94An1+gNBhwqSHQuE8BH-AHhpCR6Ox+PhSI8JFQFFAA)

Answer (score 0):

The [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) is a great match for this. `Extract` allows you to get all union type members that are assignable to your given input.

For example, given your above types,

```
// Foo is { type: 'auth'; user: string; password?: string | undefined; }
type Foo = Extract<Message, { type: 'auth' }>;
```

This type can then be made generic as you've already demonstrated above.